# ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member, unity 2019.2.4f1

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to fetch data from php api's. stuck on this error

> ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member.
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type
>   type) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:42)
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[T] (System.String json) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:30)
>   RestClient+d__3.MoveNext () (at Assets/_Scripts/RestClient.cs:34)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext
>   (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr
>   returnValueAddress) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)

here is my json response

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Yasir",
      "mobile":"0301",
      "password":"123"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Mehmood",
      "mobile":"0302",
      "password":"123"
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Imran",
      "mobile":"0301",
      "password":"123"
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "name":"Iqbal",
      "mobile":"0302",
      "password":"123"
   }
]
```

ReastClient.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class RestClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static RestClient _instance;
    public static RestClient Instance{
        get{
            if(_instance == null){
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<RestClient>();
                if(_instance == null){
                    GameObject go = new GameObject();
                    go.name =typeof(RestClient).Name;
                    _instance = go.AddComponent<RestClient>();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Get(string url, System.Action<PlayerList> callBack)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                print(www.error);
            }else if (www.isDone)
            {
                string jsonResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
                PlayerList playerlist = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerList>(jsonResult);
                callBack(playerlist);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Game.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string web_url = "";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RestClient.Instance.Get(web_url,GetPlayers));
    }

    void GetPlayers(PlayerList playerlist)
    {
        foreach(Player player in PlayerList.players)
        {
            print("Player Id = " + player.id);

        }

    }
}
```

PlayerList.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerList
{
    public static List<Player> players;
}
```

Player.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class Player 
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string body;
}
```

It's my complete code for fetching data from web api's, but getting

> ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member

I'm using unity 2019.2.4f1

Comment: right, you have id, name, mobile and password.. you declared id, title and body...

Comment: You are right but I'm only fetching id, It's not working even after declaring same variables

Comment: Have you tried using `JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Player>>(jsonResult)` instead? You aren't receiving an object with a list, you're getting a list directly (unless you didn't paste the whole response).

Comment: It's also not working

Comment: player class needs to be identical to the Json, even though you're only trying to get player id, the jsonUtility stills needs to parse the entire json to fetch that.

Comment: I changed the declaration and make it same but it still not working and showing same error

Answer (score 2):

in your response you have declared a list but the list does not have any name , how can you have a List variable without name , all variables must have names. in your PlayerList class you have a variable called **"players"** holding a list of players , but in your response you didnt declare that so in order for it to work your response must look like this :

```
{
     "Player":
     [
       {
          "id":"1",
          "name":"Yasir",
          "mobile":"0301",
          "password":"123"
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "name":"Mehmood",
          "mobile":"0302",
          "password":"123"
       },
       {
          "id":"3",
          "name":"Imran",
          "mobile":"0301",
          "password":"123"
       },
       {
          "id":"4",
          "name":"Iqbal",
          "mobile":"0302",
          "password":"123"
       }
     ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, `JsonUtility` has always given me nothing but headaches. I recommend using [Json.NET](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) instead.

In addition, @Parsa_Rt has pointed out, your Json is directly referencing the array, so you could simply extract the players this way:

```
 List<Player> playerlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsonResult);
 foreach (var player in playerlist)
 {
     print("Player Id = " + player.id);
 }
```